# Как найти ошибку в apk файле созданном в buldozer? Изначально приложение написано на Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

Создал приложение в Kivy.
При запуске в Linux все работает прекрасно.
Скомпилировал apk файл через buldozer. Компиляция прошла успешно, ни на что не ругался.
Устанавливаю на телефон. Запускаю. Приложение запускается и сразу же скрывается. Никаких сообщений не всплывает, ничего такого..
Как можно узнать в чём проблема? Куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Частично решил вопрос запуском python-скрипта напрямую из приложения PyDroid3 на Android.
В PyDroid3 Kivy уже установлен.